# URI launching a program from site and getting information from link

Tags: delphi

I have searched here for answers but I only seen few links to Microsoft c++ codes but none for Delphi so just wondering if anyone has a working Delphi example on how to launch programs from URI and get data from it to maybe connect to a socket or load a resource within my program?

Thanks

am basically looking for away to launch my program from a web address URI c++ code am none the wiser what to post as I can not understand that to save my life

and am sorry about not being more clear but I do find spelling things little hard and putting across what I would like I like to use voice mostly ha

Comment: What do you mean by "launch program from site", exactly?   Say that you know a URL - what's "at" the URL and what are you hoping to do with it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you mean how to [register your program as a handler for a custom URI protocol, as explained on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914.aspx)? If that's what you want, then please [edit] your question to explain which part you're having trouble with. If that's not what you meant, then please [edit] your question to clarify what you really want. Consider posting one of those C++ examples, just to illustrate your goal.

Answer (score 1):

You must register URI scheme for your application. For example, you may create **"myapp"** scheme. After this, if you open url like **"myapp:do_something&close"** Windows will launch your application with single parameter equal to URL.

```
"C:\program file\Soft\MyApplication.exe" "myapp:do_something&close"
```

In your application, you can read first parameter (ParamStr(1)), parse it and decide what to do.

**"do_something&close"** in my example, may be any kind of data. But if you want to open your application from web site, you may use HTTP URL format, like "myapp:\cleandisk?drive=C&askuser=yes"

[See more info what you must write into Windows Registry in order to register your own URI scheme.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914.aspx)